# Why doesn't my RESTEasy MessageBodyReaderInterceptor run in Tomcat?

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, jax-rs, resteasy, interceptor

I have a simple RESTEasy application, with methods like this:

```
@POST
@Path("/stuff")
@Produces({"application/json", "application/xml"})
public MyObject doStuff(MultivaluedMap<String, String> String formParams) {
    // do stuff
}
```

I want to intercept the message coming in, but somehow my interceptor isn't triggering. Here it is:

```
@Provider
@ServerInterceptor
@Precedence("SECURITY")
public class JAXRSInterceptor implements MessageBodyReaderInterceptor {

    public Object read(MessageBodyReaderContext context) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
        //do stuff

        return context.proceed();
    }
}
```

Here are my RESTEasy dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.4.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.4.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.4.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

And here's part of the web.xml:

```
<web-app>
    <display-name>My frontend</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.use.builtin.providers</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Frontend</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Frontend</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    ...
```

The REST service works perfectly, and I also have an [ExceptionMapper](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.3.5.Final/userguide/html/ExceptionHandling.html#ExceptionMappers) that works as it should.

The interceptors still doesn't work.  I've tried Tomcat 6 and 7.  What am I doing wrong?

I've made a simple example that demonstrates the problem at https://github.com/henrik242/resteasy-interceptor-demo.  Build and deploy under Tomcat, and access `http://localhost:8080/resteasy-interceptor-demo`.  Run tests #1, #2 and #3.

**EDIT:** This looks like a bug.  I've filed it as https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RESTEASY-797